# wxPython, Set value of StaticText()

Tags: python, wxpython

I am making a little GUI frontend for a app at the moment using wxPython.

I am using `wx.StaticText()` to create a place to hold some text, code below:

```
content = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Text Here", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
```

I have a button when clicked retrieves data from MySQL, I am wanting to change the value of the `StaticText()` to the MySQL data or what else could I use the hold the data.

I have tried using the below method:

```
contents = wx.TextCtrl(bkg, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
content.SetValue("New Text")
```

This displays the data fine but after the data is loaded you can edit the data and I do not want this.

Hope you guys understand what I am trying to do, I am new to Python :)

Cheers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`wx.TextCtrl` has a style called `wx.TE_READONLY` . Use that to make it read-only.

As a sidenode, you can use the [C++ wxWidgets Manual](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_contents.html) for wxPython aswell. Where special handling for wxPython or other ports is required, the manual often points out the difference.

Answer (score 64):

If you are using a [wx.StaticText()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstatictext.html#wxstatictextsetlabel) you can just:

```
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs): #frame constructor, etc.
    self.some_text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Awaiting MySQL Data", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

def someFunction(self):
    mysql_data = databasemodel.returnData() #query your database to return a string
    self.some_text.SetLabel(mysql_data)
```

As litb mentioned, the wxWidgets docs are often much easier to use than the [wxPython docs](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StaticText-class.html).  In order to see that the SetLabel() function can be applied to a wx.StaticText instance, you have to travel up the namespace hierarchy in the wxPython docs to the [wxWindow superclass](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetLabel), from which wx.StaticText is subclassed.  There are a few things different in wxPython from wxWidgets, and it can be challenging to find out what they are.  Fortunately, a lot of the time, the differences are convenience functions that have been added to wxPython and are not found in wxWidgets.

Comment: I certainly wondered why nothing like SetLabel was in the wxPython docs (of wx.StaticText). +1 for clearing that out

Comment: @Ariel Because it's a method in the base class `wx.Window`: [SetLabel](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.SetLabel)